# Microsoft CRM Dynamics 2011 PowerShell Error when disabling an organization

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Whenever I try the following line in a powershell script :

```
Disable-CrmOrganization -Name MyOrganization
```

I get the following error :

```
Disable-CrmOrganization : The Deployment Service cannot process the request because one or more validation checks failed.
+ Disable-CrmOrganization <<<<  -Name MyOrganization
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Disable-CrmOrganization], FaultException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment.DeploymentServiceFaul
   t, Microsoft.Crm.PowerShell, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]],Microsoft.Crm.Pow
  erShell.DisableCrmOrganizationCmdlet
```

However, if I manually disable the organization, I am able to execute the following line with no problem :

```
Remove-CrmOrganization -Name MyOrganization
```

Any idea why I cannot disable the organization with powershell?

Answer (score 1):

You might have run across this page: [Use PowerShell to Call the Deployment Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328563.aspx#ex_disable) for the CRM PowerShell references.

Running this command gives additional error details: `$error[0].Exception.Detail.ErrorDetails`

Additionally the Windows Application Event Log was showing an error (in my case anyway):

*Web service request FindItems to Report Server `http://myserver/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx` failed with SoapException. Error: The permissions granted to user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' are insufficient for performing this operation.*

Which lead me to this post:
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/0dd4a41b-eeba-405c-9b56-c32bfedb9e7a

The solution was to run the CrmDeploymentServiceAppPool under an account with elevated priviledges. Logon as a service and sysadmin in SQL Server according to the post.

[How to enable tracing in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490)

Comment: Running `$error[0].Exception.Detail.ErrorDetails` gave me `The Deployment Service cannot process the request because one or more validation checks failed.`. I am running with proper privileges, I am able to delete the organization once I manually disable it.

Comment: There is nothing more than the message in my original post.delete it.

Comment: I would enabling tracing using the *:Verbose in the TraceCategories option and check out the resulting XRMDeployment log.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will look into it later. I originally wanted to disable an organization, delete it, drop the database, restore a copy of the db and re-import the organization. I realized that in a dev environnement I can simply drop both the mscrm_config db and the organization db, and restore both without touching the deployment manager.

Answer (score 0):

when I execute 2 times it works so try with:
try {
Disable-CrmOrganization -Name "oragnization_name"
}catch {
Disable-CrmOrganization -Name "oragnization_name"
}